# Has anyone lost items in a List Folder?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

I had created folders for my List to hold older items. I did this to manage the threshold and so they would still be included in a search query.
I just noticed that the folders are empty but I know I had items in them!
I didn't lose the items they're still in the list but caused my threshold to be compromised.

I'm using SharePoint 2010 Foundation and it's very tedious to place the items back into the folders.

Has this happened to anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps to troubleshoot your issue:

1. Check if you have the permission with the folder and items.
2. Go to library settings->Versioning settings->Draft Item Security section, check if you select “Any user who can read items”.
3. Check if you have set some filter to this view in the  Modify this view->Filter section.
4. How many items in the folder? Make sure the count of items in the folder doesn’t exceed the list view threshold.